# (c++) Call a curl method twice gives and error

Tags: c++, curl

I am developing a webservice and have a small problem with curl in c++.
The following code

```
string WSUser::getUser(int id){
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
if(curl == NULL) curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    ostringstream oss;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, http://"example.com"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK) return curl_easy_strerror(res);
}
```

works fine, but the problem is, that when I call this method again

```
WSUser *wsUser = new WSUser();
cout << wsUser->getUser(1) << endl;
cout << wsUser->getUser(2) << endl;
```

then I get an error:

> Unbehandelte Ausnahme bei 0x54ba7e2c (msvcr100d.dll) in WebService.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0xfeeefee8.

Comment: How do you call getUser with 1 and 2 when it does not allow for arguments? Are you sure you are calling the right function?

Comment: Sorry for that. As I posted the code I modified it a little bit and forgot to add the parameter. It is of course string WSUser::getUser(int id){.   The function itself is working when I call it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
if(curl == NULL) curl = curl_easy_init();
```

since you don't initialize `curl`, it has an indeterminate value and using it (i.e. comparing it to `NULL`) is undefined.
What most likely happens in practice is that you will call `curl_easy_init` more or less at random, leaving a random value in `curl`.
You just got unlucky that a zero happened to be there on the first call, when it didn't crash.

You want

```
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. So I have to initialise curl just once?

Comment: @user3588661 Most of the time, you're not initialising it *at all*.